# how to deploy a mongodb replicaset using nodejs script(Automation of replicaset deployment)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database-replication, high-availability

I have to deploy a replica set using nodeJS  script.If I've to add or remove some member from replica set on a later instance of time then I should be able to do so using script. 
The problem is that I couldn't find any thing like db.initiate(config) similar to rs.initiate(config).will it be db.admin().initiate(config)?

Comment: You might look at the [ReplSetTest](http://api.mongodb.org/js/current/symbols/src/src_mongo_shell_replsettest.js.html) source from the MongoDB source as a starting point. This works as a helper in the shell to allow you to launch a replica-set for testing purposes. Similarly you can look at these under the mongo shell by simply typing `rs.initiate` without the `()` brackets at the end, which will dump the JavaScript wrapper to the underlying database command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to send replica set configuration commands via Node.js, you will need to use the replica set admin commands:

- [`replSetInitiate`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/replSetInitiate/#dbcmd.replSetInitiate) to initialise the replica set
- [`replSetReconfig`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/replSetReconfig/#dbcmd.replSetReconfig) for any subsequent changes (i.e. adding or removing members)

The [`test/tools/replicaset_manager.js`](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/1.4/test/tools/replica_set_manager.js) file in the MongoDB Node driver test suite includes some example code for managing replica sets that should be useful, in particular [`reStartAndConfigure()`](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/1.4/test/tools/replica_set_manager.js#L766).

The general steps for replica set config changes, as per `reStartAndConfigure()`, include:

- connect to the `local` database

  ```
  var connection = new Db("local", ... )
  ```
- get the current replica set configuration from `system.replset` collection:

  ```
  db.collection('system.replset').findOne({}, function(err, doc) { ...
  ```
- iterate over all the member docs and apply any config changes

  ```
    for (var i = 0; i < doc.members.length; i++) { ... }
  ```
- increment the replica set config version

  ```
    doc.version = doc.version + 1;
  ```
- reconfigure using `replSetReconfig` command

  ```
    db.admin().command({replSetReconfig: doc}, ... )
  ```

You can also see examples of how the `replSetReconfig` command is used in the `mongo` shell by invoking the `rs.add` and `rs.remove` shell helpers without the brackets.